# mkdir -p [directory to create] : What does "-p" stand for?

Tags: macos, terminal, path, command-line-interface, mkdir

In CLI command,

```
mkdir -p /data/bin
```

does the P flag stand for "path", since mkdir only creates an actual folder?

Answer (score 1):

-p is not meant for path, is to create parent directory if necessary.

In fact, you can specify

`-p or -parent`

> Create parent directories as necessary. When this option is specified, no error is reported if a directory already exists.

For example:

`mkdir -p /example/directory/documents`

Creates the directory /example/directory/documents. If *example* or *directory* do not exist, the they will be created using the -p option.